# how can I auto refresh listView in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sqflite

I implemented listView to Display the data, which I save data into `Sqflite Database`, fetched from database and display into listview. After saving data I `pop`  form fields page to listView page but my ListView is not updated, I need to move back and then open listView to see new Record.

```
  List<SubjectModel> list;
  int count = 0;
  SubjectModel subjectModel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (list == null) {
      list = List<SubjectModel>();
      updateListView();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Subject'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                new MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) {
                  return new CreateTask(SubjectModel('', '', '', '', '', '', ''),'Add Subject');
                }));
          }),
      body: getSubListView()
    );
  }

  ListView getSubListView(){
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: count,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position){
          return Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(this.list[position].subject),
                  onLongPress: () => navigateToDetail(this.list[position],'Edit Subject'),
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has to be a setState() that is called, whenever you want to rebuild anything (your listView in this example).

I would add:

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    setState(() {
      updateListView();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sir but one more thing, I getting number of count from database and set over TextView and how can I update that TextView when my counting increased ?